# ARC Semantic Issue: No Visible @Interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'loginResult:'

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, selector, semantics

I have made lot of googling about the Title above but could not get the solutions I want.
I have a project with ARC that uses a static library for service calls. When click login button credentials are passed to library and gets the response to the Login view Controller, this is where the problems occurs. i am not able to pass the data to view controller which send the request.
Here is code where the error occurs:

```
- (void)loginResult:(LoginData *)logData {
   [viewCtrl loginResult:logData]; ->No Visible @Interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'loginResult:'
}
```

in .h (Static Library class)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKIt.h>
@interface MobileWebMethods : NSObject {
    UIViewController *viewCtrl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *viewCtrl;
- (void)loginResult:(LoginData *)logData;
```

Comment: Seems like `viewCtrl` is simply an `UIViewController` and not a custom subclass that implements the method `loginResult:`. Are you sure `viewCtrl` point to an instance of your custom class? Please share some more code.

Comment: any update on this, have you made any progress or planning on adding all the code so I can review the situation ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies I didn't notice it was a NSObject class, there is a logical error here in what you are doing.

You have created a class MobileWebMethods, which is of type NSObject, not UIViewController. What you need is inside a separate viewController to import this file and create an instance of it:

```
MobileWebMethods *webMethods = [[MobileWebMethods alloc] init];
```

then call:

```
[webMethods loginResult: ... ];
```

Comment: Yes i have declared and even no case mismatches

Comment: please edit your answer to include this definition / implementation and where viewCtrl is being set

Comment: sorry I missed one thing, is viewCtrl a custom view controller or is it simply a UIViewController ???, this would not have this function inbuilt

Comment: It`s a viewcontroller and with the method declared.

Comment: I edited my answer again, Your class is of type NSObject, I thought from your previous question it was a UIViewController. there is a logical error in what you are trying to do here

Comment: I did the same and declared the method in .h file as well but of no use

Comment: the code I have above will work, this is how objects are created and used. You have made a mistake somewhere else if this did not work, try it again if it does not work please post all of the code for this file and the file where it is being called and the error. The way you are doing it above is using a lot of un needed memory and is of a very bad design

Comment: MobileWebMethods *mwm = [[MobileWebMethods alloc] init];
    [mwm loginInfoResult:loginData]; I am sending the data like this..

Comment: ... and what, what is the error ? (don't forget mwm needs to be a pointer also)

Comment: yes, type error in previous comment, Error is its saying method not mentioned but it was declared in view controller, is this problem with ARC, is it releasing the controller

Comment: no ... you don't understand object oriented programming at all. Please post the entire contents of MobileWebMethods.h, MobileWebMethods.m and the viewcontroller.m that you are using to envoke this. You have done something wrong somewhere, I have done the above 1000+ times in my applications without error. I can offer no more help until I see all the code

Comment: are you going to add the code I need to see ? you've left this question open with no solution and no accepted answer and no update as to whether its fixed or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
objc_msgSend(viewCtrl, @selector(loginResult:),logData);
```

Comment: It shows me warning "implicitly declaring library function" but control not passed to the method

Comment: import this library, #import <objc/message.h>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found your code quite confusing,you interface a class named `MobileWebMethods` which I think is a modal,and inside this modal,you have a property of UIViewController named `viewCtrl` which is a controller,I'm quite curious,why do you do this instead of obeying the Rule of the Modal-Controller-View?And I think the problem will be solved if you create  a Subclass of UIViewController and inside this controller you can create a property modal named `MobileWebMethods` wouldn't it be better?

Comment: I am using MVC only, where problem araises is getting data from model that send to controller

Comment: Well,I think sending data to the controller doesn't need to hold a controller in this modal,which is really rare in my opinion.My suggestion is that you can declare a class method in your modal like +(LoginResult *)loginResult : (LoginData *)data,and in your controller you just pass the data to the modal,and you can get the result.It's just my opinion.